# Printing out Hex?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do I print an unsigned char as hex in c++ using ostream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673240/how-do-i-print-an-unsigned-char-as-hex-in-c-using-ostream)
>   [Convert ASCII string into Decimal and Hexadecimal Representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400200/convert-ascii-string-into-decimal-and-hexadecimal-representations)

I want to print out the hex value of characters using isprint(). However, I cannot get it to work. This is my attempt:

```
getline(cin, w);
for(unsigned int c = 0; c < w.size(); c++)
{
  if(!isprint(w[c]))
  {
    cout << "ERROR: expected <value> found " << hex << w[c] << endl;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me print out this hex value? Thanks! I'm inputting things like:

í

and I want it's hex value.

Comment: Try this?  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/hex/

Answer (score 3):

By default, a char is printed as an string character. Try casting the char to a general int like this:

```
cout << "ERROR: expected <value> found " << hex << static_cast<int>(w[c]) << endl;
```