# Converting ASCII into hexadecimal in an unsigned int form using C++

Tags: c++, ascii

First of all I would like to say that this question is already related to this link ([Convert ASCII string into Decimal and Hexadecimal Representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400200/convert-ascii-string-into-decimal-and-hexadecimal-representations)) but since I cannot add a comment, I need to ask something specific related to an answer on that thread.

The code from Jerry Coffin works for me:

```
for (int i=0; i<your_string.size(); i++)
    std::cout << std::hex << (unsigned int)your_string[i] << " ";
```

but what I would like to do is instead of printing this out via cout, I would like to store it in an unsigned int variable because I need to pass this value to another function.

My code looks like this:

```
unsigned int Ascii2Hex(std::string sString2Convert)
{
  unsigned int uiHexVal;
  for (int i=0; i<sString2Convert.size(); i++)
  {
    uiHexVal << std::hex << (unsigned int)sString2Convert[i];
  }
  return (uiHexVal);
}
```

This obviously does not work because of the "<<" operator.

How can I work my way around this?

Comment: Whats the problem with just using `(unsigned int)sString2Convert[i]`?

Comment: Anything wrong with [`strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) with a base of 16?

Comment: Check this: Might help http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/89588/

Comment: It looks like you are trying to convert a string containing hex digits back into a number.  If that's the case your function is just wrong.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100718/integer-to-hex-string-in-c In the top ans, the return value is `stream.str()` probably you can store it in a string object!

Comment: Hi @RetiredNinja you are correct, that is my objective. I need to pass this value back to a device via a communication protocol so it has to be in a number form.

Answer (score 1):

Utility functions exist for this, and I believe you could use stringstreams with a similar syntax to what you actually mocked up above. Even so, there's always the quick-and-dirty way:

```
template <typename T> // Use only unsigned types or risk overflow
T ASCII2hex (std::string str)
{
    T ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(T) && i < str.size(); ++i)
        ret += str[i] << (8 * i);
    return ret;
}
```

There's also this *incredibly dangerous and technically undefined* but nevertheless elegant and strangely compelling solution:

```
template <typename T> // yadda yadda unsigned
T ASCII2hex_UNSAFE_DONT_USE_THIS_FUNCTION (std::string str)
{
    return *(T*) str.data(); // Note: overrun if str.size() < sizeof(T)!!!!
}
```

Comment: hi @acwaters thanks!

this code suggestion compiled... but how do i Call it? I get compile error when I use it. sorry for my ignorance. i just don't understand.

Comment: Right! Sorry, I should have explained a bit more. The example I gave is a function template; that means that the function can be parameterized with extra information, like types, before it's called. Basically, you can do this:

    `char[] str = "Test";`
    `unsigned x = ASCII2hex<unsigned> (str);`
    `unsigned long y = ASCII2hex<unsigned long> (str);`
    `unsigned char z = ASCII2hex<unsigned char> (str);`
You don't have to write a new version for each type; since they all do the same thing, you just tell it which type it'll be using, and it gives you the right answer for that type size.

Comment: However, you could just as well write the above as an ordinary function, returning whatever type you wish. Just get rid of the `template` and replace the `T`s with, e.g., `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

What Jerry Coffin's code is doing, despite the cast to `unsigned int`, is converting the char to a string. But usually, the `operator<<` of `cout` just thinks: "oh, char, that's a letter right..." so it prints it as the letter it represents. So to print it as a hex value instead, he casts it to an int first.

That being said, here is the problem: the code converts each character separately to an `unsigned int` and then prints it. But you want to put all the characters in one `unsigned int`. And depending on your `char` and `int` size there only fit 4 or 8 characters in an `int`. 
If it is less than this you could do:

```
unsigned int res=0;
res |= string[0] << 24;
res |= string[1] << 16;
res |= string[2] <<  8;
res |= string[3];
```

(note that here `<<` means bitshift)

So long story short, you cannot convert the whole string  unless it is really short.
But when you think about it, a string is already a list of numbers (representing characters). And remember: **numbers are always binary, until you print them as text.**

Comment: hi David, I think this could work. The ASCII string I am trying to convert is limited to 8 digits (ASCII letters if you may).

Comment: Hi @David Van Rijn I am having trouble with this solution since the ASCII text is more than 8 characters. I added some filling white spaces at the end but I actually just need the first 8. this is just in case the letters are not 8 characters eg: QLMJ2W the last 2 characters are white spaces. but to make sure, in the stringstream where i manipulate this value i added an extra 8 white spaces.

Comment: Well, you could put those in a 64 bit integer, and it does certainly speed up calculations, but it does make more sense to use a `char[8]` for this, or a `char[9]` with trailing zero. If you put it in an integer please use uint64_t. But (i don't know your application) i would write a small wrapper class for `char[9]` withe an `operator const char* ()` and an `operator<()` and the like. Then you could even define your own `operator>>(istream&, my8String&)` so you can easily pull them out of stdin or whatevever.